# How to send Contacts data through Extras while launching app through icon in Contacts?

Tags: android

I have my app's icon showing up against a Contact in the Contacts app. When I press the icon, I would like to send the phone number of the contact to my app while launching it. Where do I specify the details and pass them as Extras ? Appreciate your help.

As of now, I retrieve the URI of the Contact, get the ContactID and use that to get my App-specific information that is stored for my App's custom MimeType. If I could get a way to send the information (username) while the App icon is clicked, I could save on a bit of processing.